# What kind of supervised machine learning algorithm takes negative weights for instances?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Is there any algorithm deal with negative instance weight ?

For gradient based method it’s tricky to have negative weights since negative would cancel out other instances ?

Comment: What do you intend the weights to mean here?

Comment: Samples like this should be heavy punished? I don’t know My motivation mostly is from pure implementation